# Is there kanji(s) to mean "from court" or "court-related"?

Tags: kanji

I found a kanji for emperial court/governmental court as follows:
廷:
courts, imperial court, government office  [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%BB%B7%20%23kanji)

I am looking for an adjective for this word made with this kanji or another joyo kanji to mean "from court", "affiliated with court", or "court-related" in general.

Comment: Maybe the prefix 宮廷~? Jisho.org lists 宮廷画家、宮廷音楽, seems like what you want.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks it is a good shot